# Chrome infinite scroll with middle mouse wheel

Tags: google-chrome, mouse, google-chrome-extensions, scrolling

I am wondering if there is a way to enable infinite scrolling by depressing the mouse wheel on chrome.

What I mean by infinite scroll (not sure the most accepted term) is when you press and hold a button, then drag the mouse up or down, the further up or down you drag the mouse, the faster the velocity of the scrolling up or down.

Is there a way to enable this on chrome?

Comment: This is a function of the mouse software not chrome, see if there is a mouse setting that enables this function for the middle wheel.

Comment: No it isnt. You are thinking mouse wheel scroll, not mouse wheel press drag scroll.

Comment: Yes it is, I use it on my Logitech mouse.

Comment: Your logitech mouse has it, but it is not  a a feature of mice in general.